# ffmpeg Padding & Delay to Audio File Accurately

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg

Recently I've been doing a personal project which does entail a little bit of
audio handling but I have noticed that the commands that I am using to modify
don't have a 1:1 correlation in the resulting file leading to it being fairly
offbeat (Note that this program is error sensitive).

All I need to do is accurately add Padding to the start of an audio file, or
jumpforward to some point in the song using an Offset/Delay value. The values
are strictly accurate such as 0.13149s however accuracy passed the third radix
is pretty redundant since 'nobody' should be able to notice it.

```
Here is an example of one issue:

    [Input File Info] // This is a test case/correct values
    Supposed to start at : 0.875
    Originally started at: 1.190
    Offset Value         : -0.315
    Difference           : 1.190 - 0.875 = 0.315
```

```
    // Audio file offset attempt (FAIL)
    FFMPEG Command:  
        ffmpeg -y -i "..." -ss 0.315 -c copy -map 0 "..."
        
    [Output File Info]
    Start Time Beat         : 0.766 
    Start Time Beat Audacity: 0.766
    Resulting Error         : 0.106
```

What I want to know is if someone knows a better way to get 1:1 accuracy from
the command or atleast as close to it as possible. I don't often use ffmpeg so
I probably am missing vital information (I did my best googling ok :) but to
this I also wouldn't abstain from using a dedicated audio library for the
language I'm writing the program in (Java).

```
I probably should mention that I have been using:
    ffmpeg -y -i "..." -af "adelay=DELAY" "..."

to add the padding but I haven't really gotten around to testing audio files
that require this yet so I don't know if its broken/inaccurate.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `atrim` filter gives you accurate results:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -af atrim=start=0.315 OUTPUT
```

This is likely equivalent to using the `-ss` *output* option.

Comment: Almost perfect however It did lead me the actual problem: `-c copy -map 0` just using `-ss` alone was enough, using `-af atrim...` lead to random jumps in the output (not ffmpegs fault its just how the program interpreted the output file, the output itself was flawless)